# Разбить число на цифры в python

Tags: python

Есть переменная a = 12. 
Как разбить число, чтобы b = 1, c = 2.

Comment: Разделить на 10 и взять целое, разделить на 10 и взять остаток, просчитайте все условия и тогда будет вам полный и достойный ответ

Comment: Лениво-функциональный вариант: `b, c = map(int, str(a))`

Comment: `b,c = divmod(a, 10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = 12
b, c = [int(i) for i in str(a)]
```